# How GRUB determines the Linux root partition that it pass to the kernel with "root="?

Tags: boot, partition, root, grub

When the GRUB bootloader boots Linux, it pass the name of the root partition (where /sbin/init is) to the kernel through the *root=* kernel parameter in order for the initrd to be able to mount the real root filesystem later.

When we use the `grub-install` tool, we pass as arguments only the block device where the MBR should be installed and the place where the GRUB image and configuration files should be placed, we do not specify the root partirion with what the kernel will be booted.

How exactly GRUB determines the root partition of the system when it's installed? How is that implemented?

Comment: This is configured in `grub.cfg`.

Comment: Sure, but how it''s determined when it's done automatically by tools that install GRUB?

Comment: Source code for `grub-install` is available at `http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-install.c`